# MongoDB Nested Query Returns Only Last Occuring Result

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, socket.io

Okay, I have this code containing a nested query inside a for loop

```
var query = records.find({$or:[{starter:data},{receiver:data}]},{});//check the records table for all persons the logged in user has spoken to
    query.sort('-createDate').exec(function (err, docs){
        if(err) throw err;

        for(var i=docs.length-1; i>= 0; i--)
        {

           var starter  = docs[i].starter;
            var receiver = docs[i].receiver;
            var lasttxt = docs[i].lastMessage; 

            if (starter == socket.usernames){
              var target = receiver;
            }else
            {
              var target = starter;
            }

          usersrec.find({username:target},{}).lean().exec(function (errx, docx){
                if(errx) throw errx;

                docx[0].message = lasttxt;
                socket.emit('usernames', docx);
          });
        }
    })
```

Its meant to get the last message of each person the currently logged in user has spoken to and store in the `lasttxt` variable. 
Problem is it only gets the last message of the last user in the database 
It then then assigns this last message to everyone as their own last msg.

*This doesn't affect the database's record. just the client side*
What am i missing?

Comment: Check out these questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21829789/node-mongoose-find-query-in-loop-not-working and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31304629/mongoose-find-call-inside-for-loop-using-a-latch

Comment: If i perform a console.log(lasttxt) right before the `usersrec.find` query, it returns the right results., But the moment i place the `lasttxt` variable inside the query, it only gets the last occurrence of that field from the db

Comment: Okay, @chridam im heading there now

Comment: @chridam async is a `female dog` . I played around with sockets by emitting the needed data to and fro the client and server. And voila! it worked

Comment: Glad you sorted this. You can post your solution here for the benefit of others who may bump into the same predicament.

Comment: Oh okay. id do that now

Answer (score 1):

To navigate the js async, I did some to and fro emitting with socket.io and it worked

*on the server side*

```
var query = records.find({$or:[{starter:data},{receiver:data}]},{});//check the records table for all persons the logged in user has spoken to
query.sort('-createDate').exec(function (err, docs){
    if(err) throw err;

    for(var i=docs.length-1; i>= 0; i--)
    {

       var starter  = docs[i].starter;
        var receiver = docs[i].receiver;
        var lasttxt = docs[i].lastMessage; 

        if (starter == socket.usernames){
          var target = receiver;
        }else
        {
          var target = starter;
        }

      var userlast = target+" "+lasttxt;
                socket.emit('lastly', userlast);//Emit the username and last message for the client to emit back here
    }
})
```

*On your client side, Pick up the emitted data*

```
 socket.on('lastly', function(data){//Recieve the data and send right back
                  socket.emit('lastly2', data);
              });
```

Back on you server side, pick up the data sent back

```
socket.on('lastly2', function(data){//receive the username and last message to work with

var check = data;
var space = check.indexOf(' ');
var name = check.substr(0, space);
var msg = check.substr(space+1);

usersrec.find({username:name},{}).lean().exec(function (errx, docx){
            if(errx) throw errx;

            docx[0].message = msg;
            socket.emit('usernames', docx);
      });
```

Yeah its probably unorthodox, but at least it gets the job done. Im open to better suggestion tho